# Do I need special permission to land at a Landing Rights Airport?

Tags: faa-regulations, airport

According to the [Chart Supplement](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/), Orlando International airport ([KMCO](http://airnav.com/airport/KMCO)) is an LRA (landing rights airport).

What permission is needed to fly an aircraft to an airport classified as LRA? Can I just file a VFR flight plan, take off under VFR from somewhere in Florida, enter the class B with a clearance, and land there?

Comment: Also see [19 CFR 122.14](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/19/122.14) for requirements on getting permission to land. However a LRA seems to be only concerned with international flights, and you shouldn't have problems getting in as a domestic flight just getting in the air and getting clearance, however you'll want to call the tower before you leave to warn them and not tick somebody off trying to get commercial traffic in.

Comment: If you're thinking of flying a light GA aircraft, then [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/751/62) is relevant

Comment: @Pondlife Yeah, that question is a good reference. However, MCO has 4 parallel runways, so you're not as likely to be messing things up as at, say, JFK.

Comment: @RonBeyer Yeah, the "Landing Rights Airport" designation isn't relevant on a flight from another part of Florida. It's just a CBP designation meaning CBP will allow you to land there as a port of entry to the USA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [FAR's](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/19/122.14)

> (2) Private aircraft. The pilots of private aircraft are required to
>   secure permission to land from CBP following transmission of the
>   advance notice of arrival via an electronic data interchange system
>   approved by CBP, pursuant to § 122.22. Prior to departure as defined
>   in § 122.22(a), from a foreign port or place, the pilot of a private
>   aircraft must receive a message from CBP that landing rights have been
>   granted for that aircraft at a particular airport.

This only matters if you are inbound from an out of country origin. An LRA airport is

> Landing rights airport. A landing rights airport is any airport, other than an international airport or user fee airport, at which flights from a foreign area are given permission by Customs to land.