# Which busy commercial airports have a very large GA operation attached?

Tags: airport, airport-operations

I was thinking about OAKland International, and how the General Aviation side of the field is much larger than the commercial side, but the commercial side is still very significant.   How many others are there like that?

I don't mean the many GA fields that get occasional visits from a "United Express" or "Delta Connection" rubberband turboprop.  Let's say the criteria are

- Commercial and GA operate on separate "sides" of the airport, e.g. Most commercial traffic uses one area and runway(s) and most GA traffic uses another area and runway(s). Not John Wayne/Irvine.
- They are physically connected by taxiways, not separate airports.
- The commercial side serves over 100 flights a day of A318/B735 or larger (so not Long Beach or Billy Bishop), and is big enough to be a hub airport for a network like Southwest or Ryanair.
- the GA side doesn't necessarily dominate over the commercial side, but it has the ground infrastructure to do so if the demand were there.

Comment: Related: [Can you fly a light GA airplane into a major hub?...](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/751/18733) It's not a dupe, but some of the answers list some examples, most notably DFW (Dallas/Fort Worth).